# Count the number of lines in textarea that are all numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, textarea

I need to count the number of lines in a textarea via JQuery or plain old JS- but that's not the entire issue.

I also need to cycle through each line and match each line (maybe with some regex) all entries that are numbers- with or without commas.
I think I have a bit of regex that does the matching as required:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

The hard part for me is running through each line of the textarea and validating (and returning a count) of all the valid lines.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use `line.split('\n')` to split the input into an array of lines. Then loop through the array, matching each line against the regexp, and increment a counter when it matches.

Comment: Instea of `^|\s` you can use `\b` to match a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks! You got it. I posted an answer based on your comments.
(It's wonderful getting downvoted for trying to learn JS -_-)
I did search for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with help, thanks to Barmar.

```
function getLineCount() {
        var lines = $('textarea#my-textarea').val().split('\n');
        var count = 0;
        lines.forEach(function (line) {
            if (/(?:\b)(\d*\.?\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)/.test(line)) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        //console.log(count);
        return count;
    }
```

You can obviously make it more pragmatic if you like by taking an object overload, but my use case is more specific to a single textarea.